# Align bar charts from different sources with one xlabel each

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a pgfplot that reads from two files.
I want a bar chart where the values (bars) of one file appear over one xlabel and the values from another file over another (A and B in this example).
My current solution comes fairly close but is 1) a bit hackish as it arranges the entries in the cycle list so the charts are aligned properly and 2) does not align the bars properly with the xticks.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\pgfplotsset{
    cycle1/.style={green},
    cycle2/.style={orange},
    cycle3/.style={blue},
    cycle4/.style={purple}, 
}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycyclelist}{
    cycle1\\%
    cycle1\\%
    cycle2\\% 
    cycle2\\% 
    cycle3\\%
    cycle3\\%
    cycle4\\%
    cycle4\\%
}

\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableread{
123 11778.83 18995.27 19049.38 22236.73
}\dataA

\pgfplotstableread{
123 1925.39 7014.29 10721.35 24199.01
}\dataB

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            ybar=-1pt,
            bar width=5, 
            ymin=0, 
            cycle list name = mycyclelist, 
            xtick={0, 1},
            xticklabels = {
                A, B
            },
            enlarge x limits={abs=0.75}, 
        ]

        \foreach \y in {1, 2, 3, 4} {
            \addplot plot table [x expr=0, col sep=semicolon, header = true, y expr=\thisrowno{\y} / 1000]
                    \dataA;
            \addplot plot table [x expr=1, col sep=semicolon, header = true, y expr=\thisrowno{\y} / 1000]
                    \dataB;
        }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I am looking for is a solution that aligns the bars properly to the xticks (even better if the cycle-list-trick can be resolved).

The goal would be something like this: [image: goal]
Whereas in the MWE, the A bars are shifted a bit to the left and the B bars a bit to the right: [image: improperly aligned]

Comment: What do you mean by "align the charts properly to the xticks"? Do you mean the bars? How exactly do you want to align them?

Comment: I added a picture of the output the MWE produces: the bars are not in the middle relative to the xticks. (and yes, I meant bars not charts, edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shift of a plot depends on the plot index. Use the `forget plot` option for the plots of `\dataA` to not increase the plot index for them. Then they will use the same cycle list entry as the following `\dataB` plot and the shift will be equal for `A` and `B`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{
    cycle1/.style={green},
    cycle2/.style={orange},
    cycle3/.style={blue},
    cycle4/.style={purple}, 
}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycyclelist}{
  cycle1\\%
  cycle2\\% 
  cycle3\\%
  cycle4\\%
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
123 11778.83 18995.27 19049.38 22236.73
}\dataA

\pgfplotstableread{
123 1925.39 7014.29 10721.35 24199.01
}\dataB

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ybar=3pt,% should be >0pt
      bar width=6pt, 
      ymin=0, 
      cycle list name = mycyclelist,
      xtick={0,1},
      xticklabels = {A,B},
      enlarge x limits={abs=0.75}, 
    ]

    \foreach \y in {1, 2, 3, 4}{
      \addplot plot table [x expr=0, col sep=semicolon, header = true, y expr=\thisrowno{\y}/1000,
        forget plot% prevents increase of the plot index
        ]\dataA;
      \addplot plot table [x expr=1, col sep=semicolon, header = true, y expr=\thisrowno{\y}/1000]\dataB;}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It is possible to add a legend. To position it outside of the plot I use

```
  legend style={legend pos={outer north east}},
```

as an additional axis option. Then I insert `\legend{...}` after the foreach loop:

```
\foreach \y in {1, 2, 3, 4}{
  \addplot plot table [x expr=0, col sep=semicolon, header = true, y expr=\thisrowno{\y}/1000,
    forget plot% prevents increase of the plot index
    ]\dataA;
  \addplot plot table [x expr=1, col sep=semicolon, header = true, y expr=\thisrowno{\y}/1000]\dataB;}
  \legend{green,orange,blue,purple}
```

[image]

Or if you want different entries for `A` and `B`:

```
\foreach \y in {1, 2, 3, 4}{
  \addplot plot table [x expr=0, col sep=semicolon, header = true, y expr=\thisrowno{\y}/1000,
    forget plot% prevents increase of the plot index
    ]\dataA;
  \addplot plot table [x expr=1, col sep=semicolon, header = true, y expr=\thisrowno{\y}/1000]\dataB;
  \addlegendimage{empty legend}% empty legend image
  }
  \legend{A gr,B gr,A or,B or,A bl,B bl,A pu,B pu}
```

[image]

---

### 2nd version

You can draw two plots on top of each other:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotsset{
    cycle1/.style={green},
    cycle2/.style={orange},
    cycle3/.style={blue},
    cycle4/.style={purple}, 
}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycyclelist}{
  cycle1\\%
  cycle2\\% 
  cycle3\\%
  cycle4\\%
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
123 11778.83 18995.27 19049.38 22236.73
}\dataA

\pgfplotstableread{
123 1925.39 7014.29 10721.35 24199.01
}\dataB

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{%
    every axis/.style={
      ybar=3pt,
      bar width=6pt,
      cycle list name=mycyclelist,
      ymin=0,ymax=25,
      xmin=0,xmax=1,
      enlarge x limits={abs=0.75},
      enlarge y limits={upper=0.1},
    }
  }
  \begin{axis}[
      xtick={0,1},
      xticklabels = {A,B},
      legend style={legend pos=north west}
    ]
    \addlegendimage{empty legend}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,4}{
      \addplot plot table [x expr=0, col sep=semicolon, header = true, y expr=\thisrowno{\y}/1000]\dataA;}
    \legend{A,gr,or,bl,pu}
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=none,
      ytick=\empty,
      xtick=\empty,
    ]
    \addlegendimage{empty legend}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,4}{
      \addplot plot table [x expr=1, col sep=semicolon, header = true, y expr=\thisrowno{\y}/1000]\dataB;}
    \legend{B,gr,or,bl,pu}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly for the MWE, thank you.
However, when I add the `legend entries` options (e.g. `legend entries={A, B}`), I get the error `Missing } inserted`. Is there a workaround or even a different solution for this since `forget plot` sounds unlikely to work with legend entries?

Comment: I don't know which kind of legend you need. But I have added to legend examples and a different suggestion without `forget plot`.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you so much again.
My mistake was that I added `forget plot` to A and B instead of only A.